# "a pretty good snuff on the nose" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The NBA is adamant about one thing: It respects Morey having an opinion and hasn’t suspended or disciplined him or anything like that. It’s a fair point, although having the league itself apologize for a single individual’s comment is **a pretty good snuff on the nose**.

I saw it from [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/sports/why-the-nba-cowered-to-its-chinese-overlords-171046325.html). I haven't found the phrase "snuff on the nose" anywhere. Is it slang? What does it mean?

Comment: I'm a native speaker and I've never seen that before.  If I google that phrase I don't see it anywhere else.

Comment: Please consider waiting at least 24 hours before accepting an answer, or possibly much longer, as suggested in [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700). I'm a native speaker and I think the currently accepted answer is wrong, though I'm not sure. Writing a clearly correct answer might require more thought or research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is a metaphor.

The writer appears to be comparing the pleasure that an apology from the NBA brings (for somebody's comment) to the pleasure that snuff takers get from a good sniff of quality snuff.

Both make people feel better.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snuff_(tobacco)

Comment: Why does the author use 'on'? I feel "a pretty good snuff to the nose" looks more correct.

Comment: @dan Yes, I agree; it's a curious construction but I suspect that only the author will be able to answer the question. Authors are often not too bothered about correctness.

Comment: @dan Snuff is a powder. I would expect powder to end up *on* somebody's nose (probably accidentally) rather than being applied *to* somebody's nose (deliberately). Also, it's a play on the idiom (if not an actual example of it) of a relevant point being *on the nose*.